# Could a word stand alone between two periods?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

[The Source](http://time.com/cape-town-south-africa-water-crisis/) Time Magazine

- The word, Dramatically, is standing alone, without making at least a clause or complete idea.

> According to current projections, Cape Town will run out of water in a matter of months. This coastal paradise of 4 million on the southern tip of South Africa is to become the first modern major city in the world to completely run dry. And even though residents aren’t responsible, the burden of making sure it doesn’t happen rests largely on our ability to cut down on water usage. **Dramatically**.
>   Millions of people around the world live without sufficient access to water. But Cape Town is no developing-world urban quagmire. It is a prosperous metropolis, a well-managed global tourist destination responsible for 9.9% of South Africa’s GDP, full of multi-million-dollar beachfront properties, art museums and two of the world’s top 50 restaurants. Cape Town running out of water is like San Diego going dry. Which, if you factor in the looming threat of climate change, may not be that far off. California’s five+ year drought, which ended in 2016, had state officials scrambling to enact their own water restrictions. At one point, NASA warned that the state had less than a year’s supply in its reservoirs.

Comment: You might find [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25900/forming-valid-one-word-sentences) useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word "Dramatically" is punctuated as if it were a full sentence. But it clearly isn't a sentence (as there is no verb).

The effect that the author gets is quite dramatic! It is as if in speech she had finished a sentence, then decided to emphasise it. It suggests a rhythm that puts stress on the word "Dramatically", emphasising it.

I would not recommend you used this in your own writing, it is a difficult effect to pull off. You could have written:

> ... to cut down dramatically on water usage.

You lose the rhythmic effects, but it is more standard grammar.

An alternative would be to use the "em" dash

> ... to cut down on water usage — dramatically.

This attempts to emulate in text how one might deliver the information in speech. Some languages (I'm looking at you, Norwegian) have a distinct separation between spoken and written forms of the language. The distinction exists in English too, but it is less pronounced. Perhaps this style, in which rhythms and patterns from spoken English are used in written English is becoming more common. It can create interesting effects, but it can also get in the way of absorbing information.

Comment: Or, …cut down on water usage — dramatically(!)

Comment: It's interesting usage primarily, to me, because it’s written like the transcription of a speech: it's how you might deliver it in a presentation about climate change. It seems to be becoming more common, sometimes that’s a good thing, sometimes it just gets in the way of absorbing information.

Comment: @WillCrawford Thanks for your suggestions, I've adopted them.